# Which of the Following is Optically Active?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

> Which of the Following is Optically Active?
>
> [image]

I understand that for a compound to be optically active, it needs to be chiral and not have any planes of symmetry. I know **1** is symmetric, but I am confused about **2** and **3**.

Comment: The dotted line to HO means it is further away while the bold line to OH or HO means it is closer to you, both respective to the pentagon or hexagon. Perhaps this might help.

Comment: In the same way that you might show 1 is symmetric, do you think you could show either 2 or 3 to be symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

I am quoting from IUPAC GOLD book$^1$ .

> **Meso-compound** : A term for the achiral member(s) of a set of diastereoisomers which also includes one or more chiral members. For example:
>   [image: Not defined]

There is a plane of symmetry in the examples given in IUPAC GOLD book (shown in colour) .

[image]

Molecule $\ce{3}$ also has a plane of symmetry as shown in the figure below. This makes it **achiral**.

[image]

Molecule $\ce{2}$ does not possess plane of symmetry , and therefore **chiral**.

In conclusion , molecule $\ce{3}$ is **achiral** and molecule $\ce{2}$ is **chiral**.

**Refereneces**

$^1$ : IUPAC. Compendium of Chemical Terminology, 2nd ed. (the "Gold Book"). Compiled by A. D. McNaught and A. Wilkinson. Blackwell Scientific Publications, Oxford (1997). Online version (2019-) created by S. J. Chalk. ISBN 0-9678550-9-8. https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.